# Is it appropriate for the same person to ask a question on the site and then use another account to answer it and mark it as answered?

Tags: discussion, questions

It would appear that the person who asked [this question](https://buddhism.stackexchange.com/questions/44346/3-marks-of-existence-conditioned-vs-unconditioned-things) using the account 'Alex Ryan' proceeded to answer his own question with another account 'Maitreya' and marked his own answer as correct. Is this appropriate? He also seems insistent on spreading an off-topic link to controversial covid treatments.

The evidence this is the case comes from two comments which both accounts used that occurred within minutes of each other that stemmed from an attempt to remove irrelevant and  controversial link about alternative covid treatments.

Here are screenshots of the comments:

[image]

Compared to:

[image]

The links are: [What is the substantial cause of an instance of consciousness?](https://buddhism.stackexchange.com/q/26081/13375) and [3 marks of existence: conditioned vs unconditioned things?](https://buddhism.stackexchange.com/questions/44346/3-marks-of-existence-conditioned-vs-unconditioned-things)

The poster in question 'Alex Ryan' is insistent to post the same covid misinformation in spurious places on this site: https://buddhism.stackexchange.com/a/36652/13375

Comment: Thanks. It appears that Maitreya may be a sock puppet account of Alex Ryan. I'm also watching closely to remove or edit all posts of the user's personal website links that contain Covid19 misinformation and some off-topic conspiracy theories. If you see any comments with those links, please flag it. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

#### If this is actually happening, no, it is not appropriate.

As mentioned [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/57685/560258) by a former Stack Exchange employee

> Answering your own questions with the other account(s)

I have no reason to believe that policy has changed on this matter.

In addition, posting links to sites without disclosing affiliation (unless it's something where it is blatantly obvious that you almost certainly didn't write or own the site, such as linking to a famous news site) is spam, and posting irrelevant links that do disclose affiliation should be edited out, and if it continues a moderator can suspend the user for continued low quality contributions, if they want too.